# Prove that $f$ is differentiable on $[0,∞)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

Assuming that $e^x$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$, prove that

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\dfrac{x}{1+e^{1/x}},&x \neq 0\\ 0, &x=0\end{cases}$$

is differentiable on $[0,∞)$. Is $f$ differentiable at $0$?

Here is my textbook problem. when I asked some help from our madam she said that this is not differentiable on $[0,∞)$ it should be $(0,\infty)$ and she said  $[0,∞)$ would be typo

But I think she is wrong but I don't know exactly whether I am correct or not I know $|x|$ is not differentiable at $0$ but it is differentiable on $[0,\infty)$ or$(-\infty,0]$

Am I wrong?

Comment: Why is this downvorted?

Comment: If $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ and $A$ is a subset of $\mathbb R$, we say that $f$ is differentiable on $A$ if for any $a \in A$ we have that $f$ is differentiable at $a$. Thus, if $f$ is not differentiable at $0$, it cannot be differentiable on $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: To include 0 the limit has to be the same whether you approach 0 from both the positive and negative directions.

Comment: @azif00 if so $|x|$ is not differetiable on $[0,\infty)$

Comment: @puka That's right, $|\cdot|$ is not differentiable on $[0,\infty)$, but it is on $(0,\infty)$. In fact, $|\cdot|$ is differentiable on $\mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: @azif00 thank you very much

Comment: @puka you are right, you can consider that the function $f(x)=|x|$ is differentiable in $[0,\infty )$ (or in $(-\infty ,0]$). However the standard convention is to assume that the set where a function is differentiable is open, so we usually exclude the extreme points of an interval, in this case the point zero

Comment: Similar to continuity, one can treat differentiability at end points of interval based on one sided derivatives. However it is best to align yourself with the convention of your textbook or professor.

Comment: When considered as a function whose domain is $(-\infty, \infty)$, $f(x) = |x|$ is not differentiable on $[0,\infty)$, because it's not differentiable at $0$.  On the other hand, $f$ restricted to the domain $[0,\infty)$ is differentiable everywhere in its domain, even at $0$.  As best I can tell, you are mixing up these two concepts.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh In this example $f$ is not differentiable $0$ but it is differentiable on $[0,\infty)$ is that wrong? "it is best to align yourself with the convention of your textbook or professor" Is there any standard way?

Comment: @BrianMoehring No what I am saying is I know $f$ is not differentiable at  $0$ but when I consider one side limit it is differentiable on $[0,\infty)$

Comment: @Masacroso Why exclude extreme points?

Comment: @puka If you just redefine "differentiable" to mean the one-sided limit, then $f(x) = |x|$ is "differentiable" on $(-\infty, \infty)$, but that's not what "differentiable" means to anyone, and that's surely not what you mean.  If you want the two-sided limit on $(0, \infty)$ and the one-sided limit from the right at $0$, then you are talking precisely about the restriction of $f$ to $[0,\infty)$. (so we have to change the function)

Comment: @BrianMoehring got it in this example if I consider the domain as $[0,\infty)$ it is differentiable on $[0,\infty)$ but if its domain $\mathbb{R}$ it is differentiable on $(0,\infty)$ is that correct?

Comment: Well I don't know the standard convention. One option is to state your convention before the answer and then write the answer. I hope this should satisfy most examiners.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh In this example $f$ is diffarentiable on $[0,\infty)$ is diffarentiable is that correct?

Comment: I follow the convention of special handling at end points. So as per that the given function is differentiable on $[0,\infty) $ and at the same time it is not differentiable at $0$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I also follow the convention of special handling at end points in mind. that is why ask it however thank you there are many answers here

Comment: Also note that none of the standard theorems of differential calculus are affected by the convention we choose for derivative definition at end points. Hence the issue is not really worth pondering too much unless to satisfy some insistent examiner.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Got it thankyou very much

Answer (score 2):

$f'(0)=\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0} \textstyle {f(x)-f(0)\over x-0}=\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0}\textstyle {f(x) \over x}$
$\qquad \; =\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0}\textstyle {1\over 1+e^{1/x}}$

Now $Lf'(0)=\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0^-}\textstyle {1\over 1+e^{1/x}} =1$
but $Rf'(0)=\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0^+}\textstyle {1\over 1+e^{1/x}}=0$

Thus $f'(0)$ does not exist.
Your madam is correct.